How do I switch from silent mode to performance without the “fn” key on a Lenovo laptop?
Basically my laptop keyboard got water spilled, I got an external keyboard but it doesn't have fn key.
How do I switch from silent mode to performance without the fn key on a Lenovo laptop?

The Fn is usually interpreted in hardware and BIOS, and does not generate a scan code that can be emulated. Therefore, making a change to a firmware setting without a Fn key might not be possible.
That said, a look at Amazon, Staples and Best Buy showed many external keyboards for less than US$20 that show Fn keys in the ads.
For that matter, depending on the model of PC ("Lenovo" is not specific), a replacement for the internal keyboard might be had for the same price, and there are often online directions for installation. Replacing a keyboard takes less than 1/2 hour for a neophyte, such as myself.
